# Concurrent static file handling in Tornado is blocking?

Tags: python, nginx, webserver, tornado

I have a webserver which among other things serves static files. From this http://tools.pingdom.com report, it seems something is blocking when serving several files at the same time to the same client?

The wait-time increases for each image:

[image]

Report: http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/dgrKAX/http://arkgis.org/DIQAB7

Why is this? The files are served with the default `tornado.web.StaticFileHandler` class, but this is not the behaviour that I expected! We have a need for speed!

What can I do to fix this?

*EDIT:*

I've now set up a nginx front-end — but I actually get the same increasing connect times in pingdom.com.  Am I reading the report wrong?  Is this due to something client-side?  Or is my nginx configured wrong?

Report with nginx front-end:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nginx.

File access in Python is blocking, so the Tornado IOLoop is going to be blocked while reading from disk.

Comment: Added nginx, but still get same type report? Is this due to something client-side? Or am I reading the report wrong? Thanks

Comment: OK, if that request is taking 12 _seconds_, something is seriously wrong. It might be something to do with pingdom — I can download the larger files in a few hundred milliseconds from my laptop.

Comment: Yeah I agree, something might be wrong with Pingdom's reporting times, cause the reported pageload time itself is < 3 secs.  Thanks for your testing!

Comment: @knutole Why this answer is marked as a correct answer?! I tested opening a file in two threads with python successfully.

Comment: @mtoloo Could be that thing have changed in the last 65 months ;)